# How to wrap any component with a suspense with fallback? / 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wrote this react helper (react 17):

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const withSuspense = <TProps extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>, fallback: React.ReactNode) => {
    const SuspenseComponent = (props: TProps) => (
        <Suspense fallback={fallback ?? <div>Loading ...</div>}>
            <Component {...props} />
        </Suspense>
    );
    return SuspenseComponent;
};

export { withSuspense };
```

This allows me to wrap any component with a "default" suspense:

```js
const MyComponentWithSuspense = withSuspense(MyComponent, <div>... Loading ...</div>);

export { MyComponentWithSuspense as MyComponent };
```

However, this stopped to work (cannot find what changed).

It fails on the line `<Component {...props} />` with this error:

```
'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<TProps, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<TProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<TProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/steve/code/myproject/node_modules/@types/hoist-non-react-statics/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
              Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props
ts(2786)
```

I don't get the error.

If it matters, my deps in package.json:

```json
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "17.0.62",
        "@types/react-dom": "17.0.20",
        "typescript": "4.5.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "17.0.1"
    }
```

The package is part a pnpm workspace.

Repro here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-imuuip?file=src%2FwithSuspense.tsx